# Reactjs app deployment on AWS E2 with wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: reactjs, ssl, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, https

I have developed a `reactjs` app with .net core web **API** as backend. I have hosted the app on windows server on `IIS` with `http` which was working perfectly without any issue but when I tried to host the same using a wild card `SSL` certificate it gives this error in console of the chrome :

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

error

[image]

I have also done some configuration regarding nginx on server as well which was described in some URL.

Comment: This looks like, in your Windows server SSL certificate is not properly configured. Can you check accessing the origin URL added to CloudFront in a browser and check whether the Certificate shows as valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your reactJS application in using AWS CloudFront, and can use route 53 to redirect AWS Cloudfront url to your domain. SSL can also be easily configured once this is done

Comment: actually, I am not having AWS portal access. that is managed by the separate Information services team. I am having access to remote desktop connection to AWS windows server

Comment: well, if you have IAM access, you can use aws-site-manager to manager static sites on cloudfront and s3, see this: https://github.com/oursky/aws-site-manager. For help using site manager see this: https://code.oursky.com/aws-site-manager-opensource-site-hosting-s3-cloudfront/